# Placeholders for LSTM-RNN parameters in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I would like to use placeholders for the dropout rate, number of hidden units, and number of layers in an LSTM-based RNN. Below is the code I am currently trying.

```
 dropout_rate = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

 n_units = tf.placeholder(tf.uint8)

 n_layers = tf.placeholder(tf.uint8)

 net = rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(n_units)

 net = rnn_cell.DropoutWrapper(net, output_keep_prob = dropout_rate)

 net = rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell([net] * n_layers)
```

The last line gives the following error:

```
  TypeError: Expected uint8, got <tensorflow.python.ops.rnn_cell.DropoutWrapper  
  object ... of type 'DropoutWrapper' instead.
```

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

The Error is raised from the following code: `[net] * n_layers`.

You are trying to make a list looking like `[net, net, ..., net]` (with a length of `n_layers`), but `n_layers` is now a placeholder of **unknown value**.

I can't think of a way to do that with a placeholder, so I guess you must go back to a standard `n_layers=3`. (Anyway, putting `n_layers` as a placeholder was not a good practice in the first place.)

Comment: I would like to do hyperparameter optimization for the RNN by varying the dropout rate, number of units, and number of layers. So, I thought it made sense to use placeholders for these quantities. Can you suggest a way to do the hyperparameter search for the RNN, or refer me to an example that does this?